# Strategies for streamlining a workflow of multiple apps

Tags: c#, workflow

We have a bit of a complicated scenario in the office where we have multiple standalone applications that can also be combined into a single workflow. I'm now looking into strategies to avoid running half a dozen apps for this one workflow and I'm fairly confident that the most appropriate solution is to write an over-arching app that runs these smaller apps in sequence.

The apps don't rely on each others' results as such, but they must be run in a specific instance and you can't run step 2 if step 1 fails, etc. Roll-back isn't necessary. Some of the apps are used in standalone scenarios as well as this workflow, so it seems like a controlling application would allow me to re-use those apps, rather than duplicate code.

A controlling app also allows for the workflow to be extensible; I can "plug in" a new step between step 1 and step 2 if there is a required amendment to the workflow. Further, it should allow me to do things like build a queue system so that the workflow can just be constantly run.

Am I on the right track with my thoughts? Are there limitations to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have the source code of these smaller apps the best thing to do would be to recreate an entire application that act as a "workspace" , with the various steps of the work included directly in this bigger app.

The benefits of this approach:

- faster execution  (instead of loading every time a new process/application you will use only one)
- simpler deployment (one application is simpler than X)
- better and customized gui

2) If, otherwise, you don't have the source code of these apps , so recreating these is impossible (excluding reverse-engineering) , your approach seem's to be the only one possible for your scenario.
In this case if these apps don't have an API to use, the most stupid and working approach would be to simply use the `System.Diagnostics.Process`
 class to start a process for every app involved when is necessary to.

Here an example of this approach:

```
Process process = new Process();
string path = @"C:\path\to\the\app1.exe";
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();
```

and so on... every time you want to launch an application .

For killing these applications you have 2 possibility, kill the process manually
by calling `process.Kill()` or let the application kill herself